# Trying to merge two arrays in Laravel 7 returns Objects instead

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to merge two arrays together in Laravel 7 when getting data from a database so that I can put them in the format that I want, unfortuantly Laravel seems to return an object rather than an array which seems silly since I've getting more than one item, I would've thought Laravel returns an array of objects.

My code which isn't working because of this typeof check is as follows...

```php
$array1 = [];
$array1 = Items::where('crawled', '=', 'pending')
                          ->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')
                          ->get();
$array2 = [];
$array2 = Items::where('crawled', '=', 'in queue')
                          ->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')
                          ->get();

$output = array_merge($array1, $array2);
```

What am I missing? What's the solution here?

Comment: why are you defining a variable then immediately reassigning its value? also you can have one query that returns where 'crawled' is 'pending' or 'in queue'

Answer (score 1):

Laravel returns Collection actually. You can use [merge collections](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-merge) or convert them before to array.

```
$array1 = Items::where('crawled', '=', 'pending')
                          ->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')
                          ->get()->toArray();
```

Comment: Thanks! I think I tried this and it returned an empty array? What worked is doing: `$result = $array2->merge($array1);`

Comment: Not sure, did you put `toArray()` on both of your queries? Btw, you don't need to assign a variable beforehand to an empty array, just remove the line